# Perl REGEX: non-capturing group seems not to be working

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I have this bash statement with perl regex:

```
echo $1 | perl -pe 's|(?:://).+?(?:/)|b|'
```

prints this:

```
httpbTesting/JS/displayName.js
```

from this:

```
http://php2-mindaugasb.c9.io/Testing/JS/displayName.js
```

I was expecting:

```
http://b/Testing/JS/displayName.js
```

Maybe I don't understand something about the non-capturing groups? I thought they are supposed to match, but not capture (like a positive lookahead and look behind combined). Am I mistaken?

Comment: Re "please also advise on how non-capturing groups work", Example 1) `/ab{2}/` matchs strings containing `abb`, while `/(?:ab){2}/` matches strings containing `abab`. Example 2) `/ab|c/` matches strings containing `ab` and strings containing `c`, while `/a(?:b|c)/` matches strings containing `ab` and strings containing `ac`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use:

```
perl -pe 's|(//).+?(/)|$1b$2|'
```

Non capturing group doesn't mean that input text won't be consumed. Non-capturing parentheses group the regex so you can apply regex operators, but do not capture anything.

Or use **lookarounds** and avoid capturing groups:

```
echo "$1" | perl -pe 's|(?<=://).+?(?=/)|b|'
http://b/Testing/JS/displayName.js
```

Comment: "Non capturing group doesn't mean that input text won't be consumed." please also advise on how they work - would appreciate it

Comment: Added more explanation. You can also check: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: or `s|://\K.+?(?=/)|b|` - `\K` (not available in really old perls) sets where the consumption starts

Comment: Don't want to add another question for non-capturing group explanation, but I still don't get it. Let me illustrate by example:

Comment: Still don't quite get it. How do they differ from a capturing group then, for example: (ab){2} "ab matches the characters ab literally (case sensitive)" and (?:ab){2} "ab matches the characters ab literally (case sensitive)" - both match twice, because of the quantifier (tried on: https://regex101.com). Can you explain the difference?

Comment: Difference is that in `(ab){2}` regex you have captured group back-reference available as `$1` but in `(ab){2}` you cannot use `$1`

Comment: You wrote (ab){2} twice in the comment just above. [... ] One additional question: I have read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200514/regular-expression-matching-vs-capturing ---> but this is precissely why I thought that non-capturing group works like a look-around - I thought it matches the contents in (?: * ) but disregards them when returning. .. So, returns are available as variables and they are returned by captures, however the non-captures are still matches, just not available as variables because they are not returned?

Comment: Sorry I meant `(?:ab){2}` 2nd time in above comment. To answer your question no non-capturing group  doesn't discard the matches. It just doesn't keep it available in back-reference `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc.